# ¿Cómo obtener información del usuario logeado en Asp.Net Core usando IdentityUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityuser

¿Cómo puedo hacer para recuperar información del usuario logeado en un controlador si estoy usando IdentityUser?

¿Cómo lo puedo configurar en la clase StartUp.cs?

Mi código:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public TestController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager)
    {
        userManager = _userManager;
    }
```

Me devuelve el error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`while attempting to activate 'IntegracionDocu.Controllers.TestController'.

StartUp.cs:

```
   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(
                  Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
          services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
               .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        //**************************************************************************
        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        //*****************************************************************************
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddTransient<IReadFile, ReadFile>();
        services.AddTransient<IPaginacion, Paginacion>();
        services.AddTransient<IPeticiones, Peticiones>();
        services.AddTransient<IMetodosFtp, MetodosFtp>();
        services.AddTransient<IStockRepository, StockRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IMailingRepository, MailingRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IFunctionApplication, FunctionApplication>();
        services.AddTransient<IAspNetUsersRepository, AspNetUsersRepository>();

    }
```

Comment: Estás utilizando `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` en el Controller, pero no veo esa dependencia agregada en el `Startup.cs`. Dónde está?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo puedo configurar en la clase StartUp.cs? @Arriel

Comment: haz intentado un var myUser = User.Identity.Name; ???

Comment: Que datos necesitas obtener del usuario?

Comment: Realmente hay varias formas de obtener la informacion del usuario, puede ser por claims.Name por ejemplo o IHttpContextAccessor

Answer (score 0):

**1er Paso:**

La clase ApplicationContext debe derivar de IdentityDbContext y esta con su respectiva implementacion de `IdentityUser`

```
public  class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

**2do Paso**

Configurar en la clase `StartUp.cs` el metodo `ConfigureServices`.
Debe quedar algo parecido a esto:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
         {
             services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                  options.UseSqlServer(
                      Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
              services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                   .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddTransient<IdentityUser, IdentityUser>();
          }
```

**3er Paso:**

En el conrollador o clase que deseas recuperar el IdUser se debe inyectar por dependecias el contexto actual `IHttpContextAccessor httpContext` y manejador de usuarios  `UserManager<IdentityUser>`

```
 private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;
        public AspNetUsersRepository(IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext, UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager)
        {
            httpContext = _httpContext;
            userManager = _userManager;
        }
```

**4to Paso**

Donde nesecites recuperar el IdUser y hallas cumplido el 3er Paso  ...
la siguiente linea :

```
  var userId = userManager.GetUserId(httpContext.HttpContext.User);
```

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada para mantener la buena salud del sitio. Saludos.